# ESP IDF: Task never leaves vTaskDelay()

Tags: c, esp32, esp-idf

I am building a system that creates a WLAN AP over which the end user can Connect/disconnect the ESP to another AP ( For example a router) by posting a JSON String to a URL. In APSTA mode. When this is done a bool "_STA_START" is set to true. And the login parameters are saved in _STA_WIFI_SSID and _STA_WIFI_PASS.

I encounter a problem when writing the Task that manages the esp as Station. When the vTaskDelay() is called the code in the vTask_Manage_STA_Connection() just stops running. If I delete the statement. The code runs very fast until it casues a stack overflow and resets the esp.

start_Manage_STA_Connection() is called in main.c after I initialise the esp as Access Point.

Right now I see on the monitor that the loop in the vTask_Manage_STA_Connection runs a single time.

Below you can find my Tasks.c and Task.h

Task.h

```
#ifndef INCLUDE
#define INCLUDE
#include "config.h"
#endif

#ifndef INCLUDE_WLAN_STA
#define INCLUDE_WLAN_STA
#include "WLAN_STA.h"
#endif

 // Dimensions the buffer that the task being created will use as its stack.
 // NOTE:  This is the number of words the stack will hold, not the number of
 // bytes.  For example, if each stack item is 32-bits, and this is set to 100,
 // then 400 bytes (100 * 32-bits) will be allocated.
#define STACK_SIZE 2048


/// @brief Starts a Task to Manage the STA Connection 
/// @param pvParameters 
void vTask_Manage_STA_Connection( void * pvParameters );

/// @brief Calls vTask_Manage_STA_Connection in main.c
/// @param  
void start_Manage_STA_Connection( void );
```

Tasks.c

```
#include "Tasks.h"

static const char *TAG_Manage_STA = "Manage STA Connection";

// Task to be created.
void vTask_Manage_STA_Connection(void *pvParameters)
{
    for (;;)
    {
        // Task code goes here.

        if (_STA_START == true)
        {
            ESP_LOGI(TAG_Manage_STA, "Connecting to Station...");

            wifi_init_sta(
                _STA_WIFI_SSID,
                _STA_WIFI_PASS);

            _STA_START = false;
        }

        ESP_LOGI(TAG_Manage_STA, "Managing STA Connection...");

        vTaskDelay(100/portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    }
}

// Function that creates a task.
void start_Manage_STA_Connection(void)
{
    static uint8_t ucParameterToPass;
    TaskHandle_t xHandle = NULL;

    // Create the task pinned to core 0, storing the handle.  Note that the passed parameter ucParameterToPass
    // must exist for the lifetime of the task, so in this case is declared static.  If it was just an
    // an automatic stack variable it might no longer exist, or at least have been corrupted, by the time
    // the new task attempts to access it.
    xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(vTask_Manage_STA_Connection,
                            "Manage_STA_Connection",
                            STACK_SIZE,
                            &ucParameterToPass,
                            (configMAX_PRIORITIES-1),
                            &xHandle, 0);

    configASSERT(xHandle);

    // Use the handle to delete the task.
    if (xHandle != NULL)
    {
        vTaskDelete(xHandle);
    }
}
```

The Monitor Output:

```
I (0) cpu_start: App cpu up.
I (388) cpu_start: Pro cpu start user code
I (388) cpu_start: cpu freq: 160000000
I (388) cpu_start: Application information:
I (392) cpu_start: Project name:     wifi_softAP
I (398) cpu_start: App version:      1
I (402) cpu_start: Compile time:     Dec  5 2022 11:50:36
I (408) cpu_start: ELF file SHA256:  3597702b82953470...
I (414) cpu_start: ESP-IDF:          v4.4.2
I (419) heap_init: Initializing. RAM available for dynamic allocation:
I (426) heap_init: At 3FFAE6E0 len 00001920 (6 KiB): DRAM
I (432) heap_init: At 3FFB7508 len 00028AF8 (162 KiB): DRAM
I (438) heap_init: At 3FFE0440 len 00003AE0 (14 KiB): D/IRAM
I (445) heap_init: At 3FFE4350 len 0001BCB0 (111 KiB): D/IRAM
I (451) heap_init: At 400944E0 len 0000BB20 (46 KiB): IRAM
I (459) spi_flash: detected chip: gd
I (462) spi_flash: flash io: dio
I (467) cpu_start: Starting scheduler on PRO CPU.
I (0) cpu_start: Starting scheduler on APP CPU.
I (559) MAIN: ESP_WIFI_MODE_AP/STA
I (569) WLAN AP: Wifi Loop Started
I (579) wifi:wifi driver task: 3ffc0378, prio:23, stack:6656, core=0
I (579) system_api: Base MAC address is not set
I (579) system_api: read default base MAC address from EFUSE
I (609) wifi:wifi firmware version: eeaa27d
I (609) wifi:wifi certification version: v7.0
I (609) wifi:config NVS flash: enabled
I (609) wifi:config nano formating: disabled
I (609) wifi:Init data frame dynamic rx buffer num: 32
I (619) wifi:Init management frame dynamic rx buffer num: 32
I (619) wifi:Init management short buffer num: 32
I (629) wifi:Init dynamic tx buffer num: 32
I (629) wifi:Init static rx buffer size: 1600
I (629) wifi:Init static rx buffer num: 10
I (639) wifi:Init dynamic rx buffer num: 32
I (639) wifi_init: rx ba win: 6
I (649) wifi_init: tcpip mbox: 32
I (649) wifi_init: udp mbox: 6
I (649) wifi_init: tcp mbox: 6
I (659) wifi_init: tcp tx win: 5744
I (659) wifi_init: tcp rx win: 5744
I (669) wifi_init: tcp mss: 1440
I (669) wifi_init: WiFi IRAM OP enabled
I (669) wifi_init: WiFi RX IRAM OP enabled
I (689) phy_init: phy_version 4670,719f9f6,Feb 18 2021,17:07:07
I (789) wifi:mode : sta (30:ae:a4:80:4e:88) + softAP (30:ae:a4:80:4e:89)
I (789) wifi:enable tsf
I (789) wifi:Total power save buffer number: 16
I (789) wifi:Init max length of beacon: 752/752
I (789) wifi:Init max length of beacon: 752/752
I (799) WLAN AP: Error: Unknown AP Exception
I (799) WLAN AP: wifi_init_softap finished. SSID:myssid password:mypassword channel:4
I (799) WLAN AP: Access point started!
I (819) Manage STA Connection: Managing STA Connection...
I (91529) wifi:new:<1,1>, old:<1,1>, ap:<1,1>, sta:<0,0>, prof:1
I (91529) wifi:station: 1c:bf:ce:ca:79:de join, AID=1, bgn, 40U
I (91549) WLAN AP: station 1c:bf:ce:ca:79:de join, AID=1
I (91559) esp_netif_lwip: DHCP server assigned IP to a station, IP is: 192.168.5.2
I (91559) AP Webserver: Starting webserver
I (91559) AP Webserver: Starting server on port: '80'
I (91569) AP Webserver: Registering URI handlers
W (95189) wifi:<ba-add>idx:2 (ifx:1, 1c:bf:ce:ca:79:de), tid:0, ssn:190, winSize:64
```

Comment: Does `vTask_Manage_STA_Connection()` ever actually run? Your code appears to immediately delete the task after creating it; is that really what you intend to do?

Comment: Also, the comment in your code about stack size is incorrect. Stack size is in [bytes not words](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/system/freertos.html#_CPPv423xTaskCreatePinnedToCore14TaskFunction_tPCKcK22configSTACK_DEPTH_TYPEPCv11UBaseType_tPC12TaskHandle_tK10BaseType_t). And please don't spam tags; this has nothing to do with the ESP8266.

Comment: romkez Those comments are not from me, rather the official esp idf website "https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/system/freertos.html".  I solved the issue, I will post an answer soon. And zou are right depending on the prioritz of the task it sometimes ran just once or not at all. The issue was the lines commented "// Use the handle to delete the task."